# How can I design such a layout using CSS and styled-component as given in below Image in HTML/React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

Here is the design which I want to design

[image]

here is the design which I worked upon but unable to achieve the result.

[image]

Please suggest me the CSS styles which I can try to get the expected result as in the image 1.

Problems I am facing:

1. borders and border-radius between the children(boxes).
2. It can have N children.

```
const MetricsCardStyles = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  padding: 24px;
  gap: 24px;
  min-width: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid #807f81;

  .info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
  }
`;
```

```
export const MetricCard = ({ iconName, label, value, delta }: IMetricCard) => {
  return (
    <MetricsCardStyles>
      <Icon iconName={iconName} size={32} weight="light" />
      <div className="info">
        <Typography variant="subHeadingMedium">{label}</Typography>
        <Typography variant="superTitleSemiBold">{value}</Typography>
      </div>
    </MetricsCardStyles>
  );
};
```

here is the CSS styles is used till now and my React code.

Comment: What should happen if there is a number of elements not multiple of 3? For your border issue you might want to do a table instead of divs, but it depends on you want it to behave on small screens.

Comment: If you don't want the border, don't set the border (it's set to `border: 1px solid #807f81;` right now), or set it to `0px none transparent` to be extra sure.

Comment: thank you for your reply, @Emilien Its a desktop screen (the layout is only for bigger screens) and cards rows will also be in a multiple of 3, I can try with table.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want the borders in between but with my code the inbetween borders are getting 2px if I apply on each box.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the left and top borders on the grid that contains the cards and set the right and bottom borders on the cards.

You can set the amount of cards per row per viewport via `grid-template-columns`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  border-top: 1px solid #f00;
  border-left: 1px solid #f00;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.card {
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="card">Card 4</div>
</div>
```